# Javascript blocks conflicting with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have two javascript blocks where if one is visible then it works and same for other one. If both blocks of code are either in the same .js file or one is in a .js file and the other in a script tag in index.html, only the one page scroll works. If only the collapse code is put in and not the scroll code, then the navbar collapses fine. I can't get them to play nice with each other.

index.html

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/app.css" /> -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>


<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/nav.js"></script>
<script src="app/nav1.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse.in', function (e) {
     console.log("navbar");
   if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
       $(this).collapse('hide');
   }

});



$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function() {

    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
               console.log("scroll");
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 800);
          return false;

        }
      }
    });
  });

});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

      </ul>


      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
        <li><a href="#1">Section1</a></li>
         <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
  <li><a href="#2">Section2</a></li>
   <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Section 3</a></li>
     <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
   <li><a href="#4">Section 4</a></li>
        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div id="1" class="frontpage">


</div>

<div id="2" class="portfolio">
  <img class="line" src="port/images/line.png" alt="Line"/>
<div id="portfolioTitle">
Portfolio

</div>
  <img class="line1" src="port/images/line.png" alt="Line"/>

</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">


  <a href="#"><img src="port/images/pic1.png" class="portImage1"></a>


</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">

<img src="port/images/pic2.png" class="portImage1"/>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">

  <img src="port/images/pic3.png"  class="portImage1"/>




</div>

</div>
</div>
<div id="3" style="min-height:1000px;background:blue;"></div>

<div id="4" style="min-height:1000px;background:orange;"></div>
```

Comment: What does your browser's error console say?

Comment: Every time I've seen a question like this, it's been because of a syntax error when they combined the two pieces of code.

Comment: Why do you have `$(function() {})` inside `$(document).ready()`? They do the same thing.

Comment: You better post what's inside the index.html as well.

Comment: console isn't throwing any errors. Also I rephrased my issue above. index.html is posted above now too

Comment: Try making the selector in the first one `$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"]):not(.navbar-collapse)')` so it's not listening to events from the navbar collapser.

Comment: I think I made it like you meant. I added the code in above post. It's not collapsing still though. Let me know if I did it wrong